# Powerpoint Free Education Version - Shape Outline Weight Not Working

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I just got the free edu. version of MS Office. It shows me an option to change shape outline weight - yet, when I select various, different weights there is no change. I cannot find any way to change the shape outline weight. help!

[image: education version of power point not functioning to change shape outline size, not showing shape format options available in other versions]

Comment: The community bot apparently doesn't know much about PowerPoint. So much for AI.  Have you tried applying an outline color; for starters, something loud. Bright red maybe.

Comment: Can you explain further? What are you expecting?

Comment: I was trying to change the border width, is another way to say it. The option to change the width appears to be available, but does nothing when clicked on.
-
I also found that in the free education version, transparency was not available within boxes. I ended up getting a free month trial to complete my assignement, wherein those functions worked.
I suspect that their free version is the issue - not actually useful for students. I will be going back to google as soon as I am out of this instructor's class.